# How to restrict allowed catalog image extensions?

Tags: magento2, module, gallery-image

I created a module that overrides ImageUploader like so:

```
<preference 
    for="Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader" 
    type="MyCompany\MyModule\Model\Catalog\ImageUploader" />
```

The code looks like this (don't ask why, but we are only allowing jpg images):

```
<?php

namespace MyCompany\MyModule\Model\Catalog;

class ImageUploader extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader {

    /**
     * @param string[] $allowedExtensions
     */
    public function setAllowedExtensions($allowedExtensions)
    {
        parent::setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg']);
    }
}
```

I installed the module and the other parts work just fine. But this does not prevent me from uploading a PNG. Anyone have any ideas of what I might be doing wrong or what I should override instead of this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/di.xml`

```
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\CategoryImageUpload" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="baseTmpPath" xsi:type="string">catalog/tmp/category</argument>
            <argument name="basePath" xsi:type="string">catalog/category</argument>
            <argument name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">jpg</item>
                <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">jpeg</item>
                <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">gif</item>
                <item name="png" xsi:type="string">png</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
```

In this case, we need to override `Magento\Catalog\CategoryImageUpload`, not `Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader`.

Our custom class will be the virtual type class. So, we need to re-inject the dependencies.

Your `di.xml` should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference
            for="Magento\Catalog\CategoryImageUpload"
            type="Vendor\Module\Model\Catalog\ImageUploader" />

    <virtualType name="Vendor\Module\Model\Catalog\ImageUploader" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="baseTmpPath" xsi:type="string">catalog/tmp/category</argument>
            <argument name="basePath" xsi:type="string">catalog/category</argument>
            <argument name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">jpg</item>
                <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">jpeg</item>
                <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">gif</item>
                <!--<item name="png" xsi:type="string">png</item>-->
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

Comment: I'm on 2.1.6 and the \Magento\Catalog\CategoryImageUpload class does not exist. I did try your suggestion using \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader class, but that didn't work. I am now attempting to override \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader and seem to be making more progress there. Thanks for the tips though. It got me looking into some different places.

Comment: Yep, overriding \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader worked perfectly.